# How to obtain the staking amount for non-active validators?

Tags: staking, substrateinterface, python, polkascan

Using [substrate-interface](https://pypi.org/project/substrate-interface/) I'm trying to get the amount of DOT in staking for non-active validators, those that are waiting.
I can get the active validators' amount by using the `storage_function` `ErasStakers`, but I can't find any for the rest of the validators.

I get the `{'total': 0, 'own': 0, 'others': []}` but just for the active stakers of the current era (`Staking:ActiveEra`):

```
active_validator = substrate.query_map(
    module='Staking',
    storage_function='ErasStakers',
    page_size=300,
    params=[era_index]
)
```

Is there any call or combination of calls I could use to get the staked amount for the full set of validators (active+waiting)?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you will need to do a few queries here to get the data you want:

1. Get all validator stash accounts from iterating over the `Validators` storage map
2. Get all the controller accounts by mapping the validator stash to the validator controller via the `Bonded` storage map
3. Get the amount of tokens staked for that validator from the `Ledger` storage map

From there, you need to add up all the values to get the total amount staked.

Comment: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-debug-kit/blob/master/offline-election
may also take Kian's offline-election tool as reference

Comment: I'm not sure if I follow your idea, sorry. As an example:
- Starting with a random active validator's stash account: JACO(V05), "148CkH8YBzA1pbudK1bMo2zUMHZwbucBVH8s3utwTS687UiR". It has 2.04 MDOT in staking.
- Its controller (according to `Staking:Bonded`) is "148CkH8YBzA1pbudK1bMo2zUMHZwbucBVH8s3utwTS687UiR" with 570.9 DOT in it (500 DOT blocked for itself)
- And passing that controller account to `Staking:Ledger` I got those 500 DOT, not the 2.04 MDOT.

I'll keep trying, perhaps I'm missing something.
Thanks!

Comment: JACO does not have 2.04 MDOT personally in staking. That 2.04 MDOT number comes from all of the nominations that JACO has accumulated, specifically from being active. So for non-active validators, their number will always be 0, since no stake will be used to back them in an era where they are not active.

Comment: Exactly, that was my original question. Is there a way to know the DOT that a non-active validator for the current era has from its own and other's stake? I guess there's a way because the system must know that the validator 298th has less than the 297th and it doesn't deserve to be validating

Comment: I believe the staking system is more complex than you are making it out to be. The distribution of funds is calculated using a Phragmen Election Algorithm, and the amount of stake behind users is dynamically adjusted at the time of calculation. If you are not "active", then it does not really make sense to look up a number like what you are describing. See videos like: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MjOvVhc1oXw

Comment: @ShawnTabrizi thanks, I was somehow familiar with the Phragmen algorithm, but I guess not as much as I should. I will read about it to modify my idea of checking the staking amount for non-active validators. Thanks!